# git lfs tracking file of type where size is above

Tags: git, git-lfs

So i am using `git lfs` in my unity project.

Now in unity, a file called `.asset` doesn't necessarily mean that it is huge but it can grow to a huge amount over time.

my question is:

**is it possible to track .asset files that has a size above 50mb ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git lfs road map (https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/ROADMAP.md) lists this as a possible feature; so as of now, that appears to be a no.

Answer (score 2):

How about find + git lfs?

```
find "*.asset" -type f -size +50M -exec git lfs track {} \;
```